# JQuery AJAX call, IE9 issues with JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, internet-explorer-9

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/D2s2M/1/

I cannot figure out why this does not work in IE9.  I've seen other questions here on Stack with similar issues, none of which have solutions that seem fix my problem.

This issue is specific to IE9, it **does** work in FF and Chrome. However, I am seeing some oddities in Chrome that do not make sense: if I append the `contentType:'application/json'` inside of the attributes, it breaks functionality inside of Chrome.

Here is the code that is in fiddle:

```
$('document').ready(function(){  
    $.ajax({
      dataType: 'json',
      type:'GET',
      url: 'https://freegeoip.net/json/?callback=',
      //contentType: 'application/json',
      success: function(response, status, xhr){ 
        var ct = xhr.getResponseHeader("content-type") || "";
        $('#text').text(ct);
      },
      error: function(a,b,c) {
          $('#text').text('Error: '+' '+b+' '+c);
      },
      timeout: 3000
  });  
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
dataType: 'json',
```

to

```
dataType: 'jsonp',
```

Comment: Thanks, tried this in fiddle and got: `parsererror Error: jQuery19105214428892359138_1391817248266 was not called`

Comment: I'm going to upvote this as it led me to my solution.

Comment: And when it is jsonp, the content type should not be json.

Comment: @Russell, FYI, that thread I linked to mentioned JSONP as a potential workaround...

Answer (score 0):

**Solution: http://jsfiddle.net/D2s2M/2/**

I'm not precisely sure why this cross-domain issue was IE specific nevertheless, JSONP did lead to resolving the issue.

The service I'm using does support JSONP, in the url there is a querystring variable to specify the name of the callback you wish to use. (JSONP requires that the data either be wrapped in a callback inside of the file itself, or set and passed an object inside of the JSON file.. this is required because JSONP loads everything in the head of the DOM to bypass cross-domain restrictions).

**Revised Code:**

```
$('document').ready(function(){  
$.ajax({
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      type:'GET',
      url: 'https://freegeoip.net/json/?callback=func',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      async: false,
      jsonpCallback: 'func',
      success: function(data){ 
        console.log(data);
      },
      error: function(a,b,c) {
          $('#text').text('Error: '+' '+b+' '+c);
      },
      timeout: 3000
  });  
});
```